# IndexOutOfRangeException after creating this method in C#

Tags: c#

I keep getting IndexOutOfRangeException after creating this range match method in C#. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
private string RangeMatch(char lastnameLetter, char[] letterLimits, string[] times)
{
     string regTime;
     int index = letterLimits.Length - 1;

     while (index >= 0 && lastnameLetter < letterLimits[index])
            --index;

     regTime = times[index];
     return regTime;
}
```

Comment: Read the exception and debug accordingly.

Comment: I think you want to use `while (index > 0 && ...`; if you allow `index` to reach zero in that condition, and _then_ decrement `index` one more time, you get an `index` value of -1.

Comment: When I set index to >0 the method will only return the last element of the of the times array - no matter what char is given for the lastnameLetter.

Answer (score 1):

You must assign array index with non-negative, integer, number.

Your last statement before `return`:

```
regTime = times[index];
```

may have `index` value of `-1` due to the previous while loop:

```
 while (index >= 0 && lastnameLetter < letterLimits[index])
        --index;
```

This happens when `index >= 0` and `lastnameLetter < letterLimits[index]` till the end (perfect match).

One fix would be to `return null` when `index` is `-1`, before the assignment. You could also combine the condition to return null with some other possible errors (like `times == null` or `times.Length < index - 1`)

```
private string RangeMatch(char lastnameLetter, char[] letterLimits, string[] times)
{
     string regTime;
     int index = letterLimits.Length - 1;

     while (index >= 0 && lastnameLetter < letterLimits[index])
            --index;

     if (index == -1 || times == null || times.Length < index - 1) //invalid cases
         return null; //return null

     regTime = times[index];
     return regTime;
}
```

Comment: I understand that index may have a value of -1, I'm just not sure why or how to fix it.

Comment: @BrookeG one simple fix would be to `return null` when the index is -1: `if (index == -1) return null;`, before you assign `regTime = times[index];`